# mysql query with C

Tags: mysql, c

I am writing a program where the user is giving random 10 bytes which I am storing in a buffer.  Then search the hexadecimal string in a MySql database.

```
unsigned char buffer[10];   //Example:-  {23, 181, 185, 192, 101, 156, 61, 247, 206, 204}

//convert each byte into 2 digit hexadecimal characters and store it in an array.
unsigned char hex_bytes[21];
for(int i = 0, l = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    int decimal_num = buffer[i];
    int quotient, remainder;
    char hex_num[10];

    quotient = decimal_num;
    int j = 0;
    while(quotient != 0) {
        remainder = quotient % 16;
        if(remainder < 10) {
            hex_num[j++] = 48 + remainder;
        }
        else  {
            hex_num[j++] = 87 + remainder;    //hex_num[j++] = 55 + remainder;
        }
        quotient = quotient/16;
    }
    for(int k = j-1; k >=0; k--) {
        hex_bytes[l++] = hex_num[k];
    }
}
printf("Ticket no. = %s\n", hex_bytes);

//------------------------------------------------------------------//

//Querying the Database

unsigned char query1[256];
uint32_t nos[10000];
MYSQL_RES *result;
//unsigned char* hex_str = "17b5b9c0659c3df7cecc";   <-----
//sprintf(query1, "SELECT sn FROM fixit_log WHERE rn = '%s'", hex_str);  <-----

sprintf(query1, "SELECT sn FROM fixit_log WHERE rn = '%s'", hex_bytes);
mysql_query(con, query1);
if(mysql_errno(con) != 0) {
    printf("stderr: %s\n", mysql_error(con));
    mysql_close(con);
    return;
}
result = mysql_store_result(con);
int k = 0;
for(int i =0; i < sr_nos_size; i++) {
    MYSQL_ROW row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
    printf("--sn: %2s\n", row[0]);
    }
}
```

My Database looks like this:

```
          sn                   rn

        123456           17b5b9c0659c3df7cecc  ///hexadecimal string of the given example as stored in the database
        123457           17b5b9c0659c3df7cecc
        123458           17b5b9c0659c3df7cecc
```

If I hardcode the hexadecimal string(comment out // part), I am getting the proper output. But if I run the program as above I am don't get any output.

Comment: Some [MCVE] should be usefull. Can't you display the query your program is trying to execute and run it in another env?

Comment: your `while (quotient != 0) { /*...*/ quotient = quotient / 16; }` will loop only once when `quotient` is below 16... and not at all when `quotient` is 0.

Comment: What is your question? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the issue with the code.